# The html '<' and '>' will Disappear

Tags: wordpress

I've done copy the follow code in my ChildTheme functions.php , but it did not work yet:

> ```
> remove_action('init', 'kses_init');
> remove_action('set_current_user', 'kses_init');
> ```

1 When I write some code in the HTML MODE, such as:

> ```
> <pre>
> <div>why the DIV outside will disappear? </div>
> hello() => 'hello world';   //The '>' will disappear as well
> </pre>
> ```

2 But change it to WRITE MODE, it is not what I expect, and back to HTML MODE, it goes on like this:

> ```
> <div>why the DIV outside will disappear?</div>
> <pre>hello() =&gt; 'hello world';   //The '&gt;' will disappear as well
> </pre>
> ```

3 And when I preview the post, the page appears like this (> change into *&gt ;*):

why the DIV outside will disappear?

```
hello() =&gt; 'hello world';   //The '&gt;' will disappear as well
```

And now I wonder if it caused by the plugin WP Code Highlight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to html encode the html entities. In php you can use the function [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Basically `<` and `>` are control chars which need to be *escaped* with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The `&` sign needs also to be replaced with `&amp;`.